# Customizing the settingflyout (Callisto) in c#/xaml ,how to not show the default settingpane on press of top backbutton of settingflyout?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

Hi  i am using a settingflyout present in Callisto in my windows 8 metro app in this way :-

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += MainPage_CommandsRequested;
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SettingsPane.Show();

        }



        void MainPage_CommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            SettingsCommand storage = new SettingsCommand("SettingsW", "Settings Wide", (x) =>
            {
                SettingsFlyout settings = new SettingsFlyout();
                settings.FlyoutWidth = Callisto.Controls.SettingsFlyout.SettingsFlyoutWidth.Wide;
                settings.HeaderText = "Settings Wide";

                settings.Content = new CallistoSettings.SettingsViews.SettingsWide();
                settings.IsOpen = true;
            });
            args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(storage);

            // Settings Narrow
            SettingsCommand settingsNarrow = new SettingsCommand("SettingsNarrow", "Settings Narrow", (x) =>
            {
                SettingsFlyout settings = new SettingsFlyout();
                settings.FlyoutWidth = Callisto.Controls.SettingsFlyout.SettingsFlyoutWidth.Narrow;
                settings.HeaderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                settings.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
                settings.HeaderText = "Settings Narrow";

                settings.Content = new CallistoSettings.SettingsViews.SettingsNarrow();
                settings.IsOpen = true;
            });
            args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(settingsNarrow);


            // About
            SettingsCommand about = new SettingsCommand("About", "About", (x) =>
            {
                SettingsFlyout settings = new SettingsFlyout();
                settings.FlyoutWidth = Callisto.Controls.SettingsFlyout.SettingsFlyoutWidth.Narrow;
                settings.HeaderText = "About";

                settings.Content = new CallistoSettings.SettingsViews.About();
                settings.IsOpen = true;
            });
            args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(about);
        }
    }
```

but my doubt is:-

1) it opens the required flyout on which i pressed on , but on the top there is back button on which if i press it opens the setting pane , but i dont want to open the setting pane
(if the user presses on back button which is present on top of settingflyout , the settingflyout should be dismissed(in the way it happnes if i press outside of setting pane(light dismissed) )

all i want is that on press i should get the settingflyout  and even if the user presses on settingflyout backbutton also it should close the settingflyout instead of showing the default setting pane.

please let me know how can i achieve this .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to display the button, then it should behave as coded in the control - the user will expect the behaviour you see now.  If you don't want that behaviour, why not just remove / disable the button altogether?  Again, though, you will run foul of design guidance that says you should have this control.

The message here is that users expect certain behaviour, and your app will probably annoy them if it doesn't do what they expect.

Comment: but i am not able to disable the backbutton present (since it comes by default and we dont have control on that ) , so how can i do this ?, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

use  `SettingsPane.ShowIndependent();` instead.